# How to view json List of Map data in ListView builder

Tags: flutter-layout

1. "images":[
   {
   "id":11,
   "imageName":"xCh-rhy"
   },
   {
   "id":31,
   "imageName":"fjs-eun"
   }   ];

Comment: Please help me !

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Create model,

   ```
    class Image {
        final String id;
        final String name;

        Images({this.id, this.name});
    }
   ```
2. Parse & Add Data,

   ```
    List<Image> parsedImages = [];
    List<dynamic> jsonImages = jsonData["images"];
    jsonImages.forEach(
        (imgInfo) {
            parsedImages.add(
                Image(
                    id: imgInfo["id"],
                    name: imgInfo["imageName"],
                )
            );
        }
    );
   ```
3. Build List,

   ```
    ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(parsedImages.name));
        },
        itemCount: parsedImages.length,
    )
   ```